# Android asset file or directory

Tags: android, kotlin, android-assets

I am trying to list all the files in an assets subdirectory (including sub-subdirectories) but when it comes to identify if a file is a regular file or directory I got stuck.

The directory tree can look like this:

```
assets/imports
assets/imports/set_one/...(multiple files)
assets/imports/set_two/...(multiple files)
assets/imports/...(other optional files and directories)
```

What I've tried so far is here:

```
val IMPORTS_PATH = "imports"
val assetFileNames = context.assets.list(path)!!.asList()
for(file in assetFileNames) {
    val subPathString = "$IMPORTS_PATH/$file"
    val isDir1 = File(subPathString).isDirectory //always false,
    val isFile1 = File(subPathString).isFile //always false, same as above
    
    val subPathObj = Paths.get(subPathString)
    val isDir2 = Files.isDirectory(subPathObj) //always false, same as above
```

I've even tried to read file attributes but got NoSuchFileException although the file does exist.

Is there a clean way to tel if a file is a directory or just regular file?

Comment: Assets are files only on your development machine. They are entries in a ZIP-style archive on the device (your APK file). You cannot use `File` or `Files` with Android assets on the device.

Comment: Not sure I get what "Assets are files only on your development machine" means. They are still files and part of the APK. If I can't use File or Paths or any other Java style NIO/IO is fine but what's the best way to tell the difference?

Comment: "They are still files" -- they are not files on the phone.

Comment: Ok, got what you meant. Now it's clear why NIO and IO does not work. I've checked other Stackoverflow questions and they are pretty much hacks. Well, I guess I'll have to adopt one of those solutions.

Comment: Tbh I thought that the API can read inside the ZIP... I guess I'm asking too much.

Comment: If you can open an input stream for the entry its a file. Else a directory.

Comment: "I thought that the API can read inside the ZIP" -- it does. The ZIP format does not really have the notion of "directories". ZIP entries have names, and those names can have separators like `/` that could be considered directories. The assets API basically maps directly to how ZIP files work.

Comment: I meant IO/NIO api not assets api. Anyway, point taken. It all makes sense now.